# Fastest one for apply function to update whole rows of specific column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

I have some large DataFrame(x million rows).
I have to update specific column values (whole rows) to the hashed one.
I want to know the simple and fastest way to do it.

It's a sample code.

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import hashlib

def hash(value: str) -> str: 
    result = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac(
        "sha256",
        value.encode("utf-8"),
        salt="sample".encode("utf-8"),
        iterations=100,
    )

    return result.hex()

n = 100000

df = pd.DataFrame({
        "col1": np.random.normal(size=n),
        "col2": np.random.normal(size=n),
        "col3": np.random.normal(size=n),
    }
    , dtype=str)

# target columns
columns = ["col1", "col3"]

# what I've tested
%timeit df[columns].applymap(hash)
%timeit for c in columns: df[c].apply(hash)
%timeit np.frompyfunc(hash, 1, 1)(df[columns].to_numpy())

# Note: Finally, I have to do something like this
# df[columns] = df[columns].applymap(hash)
# df.to_csv("sample.csv")
```

The three examples in the sample code are almost same performance.
I know vectorization is important for python.
But I can't figure out how I make it vectorized..

Could anyone help me find an answer?

Comment: It doesn't look like your problem requires vectorization as each element is independent of each other when it comes to calculating the hashed value. However, you can parallelize your function on the df using dask's [applymap](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.applymap).

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr Thanks for your comment! I understand that it's not a matter of vectorization. I tried dask's applymap. Then I got it faster on my environment. 

P.S.
I have to execute it on the Azure Functions, but It run properly on there. (I know that such like heavy process is not suitable for Functions..)

Answer (score 0):

I added one that uses dask's applymap. Thank you,  Scratch'N'Purr.
It works well (x2.74 faster on my machine).

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import hashlib
import dask.dataframe as dd
import multiprocessing

def hash(value: str) -> str: 
    result = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac(
        "sha256",
        value.encode("utf-8"),
        salt="sample".encode("utf-8"),
        iterations=100,
    )

    return result.hex()

n = 100000

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1": np.random.normal(size=n),
    "col2": np.random.normal(size=n),
    "col3": np.random.normal(size=n),
    }
    , dtype=str)


# target columns
columns = ["col1", "col3"]

# what I've tested
%timeit -r 1 df[columns].applymap(hash)
%timeit for c in columns: df[c].apply(hash)
%timeit np.frompyfunc(hash, 1, 1)(df[columns].to_numpy())

# added one
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
%timeit -r 1 ddf[columns].applymap(hash).compute()
```